# React components not spanning correctly when used with a CSS-Grid component

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I made a CSS-grid component and am placing other React components into it.
Everything is rendering fine, except that the components are not spanning across the grid-areas like they should. They simply are being placed across the areas in the order they are laid out, without spanning across areas. Does this have something to do with the lack of support for subgrids?

What I'm getting:
[image]

What I want to get:
[image]

```js
// APP.js 

// Grid cell
const Cell = props => (
  <div>{props.children}</div>
);

Cell.propTypes = {
  area: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default () => (
  <div className={css.container}>
    
    <h2>Grid</h2>
    <Grid

      A={props => <Cell area={props.area}><HeaderLoggedIn /></Cell>}
      B={props => <Cell area={props.area}><EditorButtonBar /></Cell>}
      C={props => <Cell area={props.area}><EditorPreviewBar /></Cell>}
      D={props => <Cell area={props.area}><EditorSidebarLogin /></Cell>} />
      
  </div>
);
```

```css
/* GRID COMPONENT CSS */

.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a"
    "b"
    "d"
    "c"
    "e";
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
}

.e {
  grid-area: e;
}


@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 330px;
    grid-template-areas:
    "a a"
    "b b"
    "c d"
    "e d";
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- GRID COMPONENT HTML -->

import React from 'react';
import css from './grid.scss';

export default props => (
  <div className={css.grid}>
    <props.A area={css.a} />
    <props.B area={css.b} />
    <props.C area={css.c} />
    <props.D area={css.d} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: [No browser has an implementation of subgrid as yet.](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/03/16/subgrid-moved-to-level-2-of-the-css-grid-specification/)

Comment: I'm not directly using display: subgrid;
However, is what I am trying to achieve impossible without subgrid?

Comment: It's possible with Grid. Not sure about React. Can you post a working demo? We can help you more effectively if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/synapse709/pen/WZEMvL?editors=1100
This is the grid that works perfectly fine when using plain html/css.

As soon as I try to do it in the way I have posted above (with components being dropped into a separate css-grid component) it stops spanning correctly. I have no problem getting it to work when I use a css-grid that is not a separate component.

(the html/css of the individual components I am placing into the separate css-grid component doesn't matter as I've tested it with the same css as this codepen (IE: simple colors))

Comment: i was facing a similar issue, but when i change `girid-template-areas` to grid-template-rows and grid-template-columns, they worked fine

Comment: SOLVED:
Added the below to app.js

// Grid cell
const Cell = props => (
  <div className={props.area}>{props.children}</div>
);